# Как в моем случае правильно обратиться к переменным другого класса

Tags: java

хочу разнести змейку в Eclipse по файлам - классам, чтобы не было помойки в одном. при запуске все работает, создаю новый класс - переношу туда код, ругается что переменные не определены (оно и понятно), но как мне обратится к ним или передать их? В моем случае например переменные snake и food.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameSnake {

    // Константы поля//
    final String TITLE_OF_PROGRAM = "Classic Game Snake";
    final String GAME_OVER_MSG = "GAME OVER";
    final int POINT_RADIUS = 20; // кругляшок в пикселях еда, и тд
    final int FIELD_WEIGHT = 30; // ширина поля в поинтах 30*20 по 20 пикс поле
    final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 20; // высота поля в поинтах 30*20 по 20 пикс поле
    final int FIELD_DX = 6;
    final int FIELD_DY = 28;

    final int START_LOCATION = 200;

    // Константы змейки//
    final int START_SNAKE_SIZE = 6; // стартовая длина змейки. состоит из 6
                                    // секций
    final int START_SNAKE_X = 10; // стартовая позиция змейки в поинтах
    final int START_SNAKE_Y = 10; // стартовая позиция змейки в поинтах
    final int SHOW_DELAY = 150; // задержка для перерисовки чтобы движения
                                // замедлять
    final int LEFT = 37; // код клавиши
    final int UP = 38;
    final int RIGHT = 39;
    final int DOWN = 40;
    final int START_DIRECTION = RIGHT; // первоначально змейка будет двигаться
                                        // направо
    final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.black; // цвет змейки
    final Color FOOD_COLOR = Color.green; // цвет еды
    final Color POISON_COLOR = Color.red; // цвет опасности

    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    // Poison poison;

    JFrame frame;
    Canvas canvasPanel; // конва
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean gameOver = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameSnake().go();
    }

    void go() {

        frame = new JFrame(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM + " : " + START_SNAKE_SIZE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(FIELD_WEIGHT * POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DX, FIELD_HEIGHT * POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DY);
        frame.setLocation(START_LOCATION, START_LOCATION); // стартовое
                                                            // положение окна
        frame.setResizable(false);

        canvasPanel = new Canvas(); // где все выводится
        canvasPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, canvasPanel);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                snake.setDirection(e.getKeyCode());

            }

        });

        frame.setVisible(true);

        snake = new Snake(START_SNAKE_X, START_SNAKE_Y, START_SNAKE_SIZE, START_DIRECTION);
        food = new Food();

        while (!gameOver) {
            snake.move();
            // проверяем съедена ли еда//
            if (food.isEaten()) {
                food.nextFood();;
            }

            canvasPanel.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(SHOW_DELAY);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public class Snake {

        ArrayList<Point> snake = new ArrayList<Point>(); // массив объектов
        int direction;

        public Snake(int x, int y, int length, int direction) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Point point = new Point(x - i, y);
                snake.add(point);
            }
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        boolean isInsideSnake(int x, int y) {

            for (Point point : snake) {
                if ((point.getX() == x && point.getY() == y)) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

        boolean isFood(Point food) {

            // совпали координаты головы змейки и еды
            return (snake.get(0).getX() == food.getX() && snake.get(0).getY() == food.getY());
        }

        void move() {
            // берем координаты головы и меняем в зависимости от направления
            // движения
            int x = snake.get(0).getX();
            int y = snake.get(0).getY();

            if (direction == LEFT) {
                x--;
            }
            if (direction == RIGHT) {
                x++;
            }
            if (direction == UP) {
                y--;
            }
            if (direction == DOWN) {
                y++;
            }

            // выходя за край появляется с другой стороны*
            if (x > FIELD_WEIGHT - 1) {
                x = 0;
            }
            if (x < 0) {
                x = FIELD_WEIGHT - 1;
            }
            if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) {
                y = 0;
            }
            if (y < 0) {
                y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1;
            }
            //проверка чтоб змейка не врезалась в саму себя//
            gameOver = isInsideSnake(x, y);


            // *
            // добавляем к голове элемент но убираем хвост (для движения)
            snake.add(0, new Point(x, y));
            // проверяем столкновение головы змейки с едой
            if (isFood(food)) {
                food.eat();
                frame.setTitle(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM + " : " + snake.size());
            } else {

                snake.remove(snake.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        void setDirection(int direction) {
            if ((direction >= LEFT) && (direction <= DOWN)) {

//проверка чтоб змея сама в себя не входила при управлении влево блокируя движения
                if (Math.abs(this.direction - direction) !=2) {
                    this.direction = direction;
                }
            }

        }

        void paint(Graphics g) {
            for (Point point : snake) { // перебирает элементы snake и по мере
                                        // выбора посылает в переменную point
                                        // цикл foreach
                point.paint(g);
            }
        }
    }

    class Food extends Point {

        public Food() {
            super(-1, -1);
            this.color = FOOD_COLOR;

        }

        void eat() {
            // устанавливаем координаты еды отрицательные//
            this.setXY(-1, -1);
            ;
        }

        boolean isEaten() {

            return this.getX() == -1;// значит еду съели

        }

        void nextFood() {
            int x, y;
            do {
                x = random.nextInt(FIELD_WEIGHT);
                y = random.nextInt(FIELD_HEIGHT);
            } while (snake.isInsideSnake(x, y));

            this.setXY(x, y);

        }

    }

    public class Point {
        int x, y;
        Color color = DEFAULT_COLOR;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.setXY(x, y);
        }

        void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x * POINT_RADIUS, y * POINT_RADIUS, POINT_RADIUS, POINT_RADIUS);

        }

        int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        void setXY(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

        }

    }

    public class Canvas extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            snake.paint(g);
            food.paint(g);


            if(gameOver){
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,40));
                //вычисляем ширину экрана и устанавливаем надпись по центру
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                g.drawString(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WEIGHT*POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DX - fm.stringWidth(GAME_OVER_MSG))/2, (FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DY)/2);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируйте эти переменные в конструкторе класса GameSnake:

```
public GameSnake() {
    snake = new Snake(START_SNAKE_X, START_SNAKE_Y, START_SNAKE_SIZE, START_DIRECTION);
    food = new Food();
}
```